# SQLAlchemy: ForeignKey across schemas

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In my `postgres` server we have a database `database` with 2 schemas: `public` and `api`.
`public` has several tables, and I need to create a table in `api` with a foreign key to a table in `public` called `model`.
So it's:

```
-Schemas
--public
---tables
----models
--api
---tables
```

Using SQLAlchemy I have the following class:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column

class __PostgresService:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__client = create_engine("postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/database")
    metadata = MetaData(self.__client, schema="public")
    self.__table = Table("training", metadata,
                         Column("id", String, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
                         Column("model_id", ForeignKey("model.id"), nullable=False),
                         schema="api")
    metadata.create_all()

postgres_service = __PostgresService()
```

However upon launch I receive the following error:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'training.model_id' could not find table 'public.model' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

It seems it does look for the correct thing but can't find it? I'm very confused as to why this is happening, especially because the error refers to not finding "public", which is created by default by `postgres`, rather than "api" which I created myself in pgAdmin.
Am I missing some cruicial config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting means that you are trying to create a foreign key referencing a table that SQLAlchemy does not know about. You can tell sqlalchemy about it by creating a `Table` associated with the same `MetaData` describing the referenced table. You can also do this using sqlalchemy's [reflection capabilities](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html?highlight=reflection#reflecting-database-objects). For example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column
    
class __PostgresService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__client = create_engine("postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/database")
        metadata = MetaData(self.__client, schema="public")
        metadata.reflect(schema="public", only=["model"])
        self.__table = Table("training", metadata,
                Column("id", String, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
                Column("model_id", ForeignKey("model.id"), nullable=False),
                schema="api")
        metadata.create_all()

        postgres_service = __PostgresService()
```

By default, `MetaData.create_all()` will check for the existence of tables first, before creating them, but you can also specify the exact tables to create: `metadata.create_all(tables=[self.__table])`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I do need to only create the table if it exists so this is fine.